# copy link to clipboard with jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I've been following some post about this, but I'm unsure why is not working. It creates the input with the correct info, but it doesn't copy to the clipboard, I'm not sure if it has something to do wit being generated dynamically

**Script**

```
//copy to clipboard
$(document).on('click', '[data-action=copy]', function (){
    /* Create input */
    $('[data-action=copy]').after('<input class="hide" value="'+$(this).attr("data-url")+'" id="share-url">');

    /* Get the text field */
    var copyText = document.getElementById("share-url");

    /* Select the text field */
    copyText.select();

    /* Copy the text inside the text field */
    document.execCommand("copy");

    /* Alert the copied text */
    alert("copied");
});
```

**html**

```
<a data-action="copy" data-url="whatever to copy" href="#">
    <img src="{{ cdn('/img/social/link.png') }}" >
</a>
```

Comment: check jQuery version, It works with 2.0.3

Comment: Some browsers disable this feature for security reasons (the clipboard belongs to the user).

Comment: the problem is with hide, when it's hidden, it's not copying..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem is that you can't hide the input to copy it.
Try this little hack instead `style="position: absolute; left: -1000px; top: -1000px"`